# Extract Javascript data using map(), filter() and concatAll() functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The output is almost correct, but I am having trouble flattening the nested boxart array.

**Javascript data:**

```
var movieLists = {
    name: "Instant Queue",
    videos : [
        {    
             "id": 70111470,
             "title": "Die Hard",
             "boxarts": [
                 {width: 150, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg"}, 
                 {width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg"}
             ],
            "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
            "rating": 4.0,
            "bookmark": [{ id:432534, time:65876586 }]
        },
        {
            "id": 654356453,
            "title": ....,
        }];
```

**Expected Output:** (using only the functions`.map()`, `.filter()`, `.concatAll()`, return id, title, boxart:url of films which have the boxart image dimensions 150x200

```
// [
//     {"id": 675465,"title": "Fracture","boxart":"http://cdn-0...." },
//     {"id": 65432445,"title": "The Chamber","boxart":"http://cdn-0...." },
//     {"id": 654356453,...}
// ];
```

**Current Output:**

```
// [                                    //boxart value is an array
//     {"id": 675465,"title": "Fracture","boxart":["http://cdn-0...."]},
//     {"id": 65432445,"title": "The Chamber","boxart":["http://cdn-0...."]},
//     {"id": 654356453,...}
// ];
```

**My Solution**:

```
return movieLists.map(function (category) {
   return category.videos.map(function (video) {
       return {
           id: video.id,
           title: video.title,
           boxart: video.boxarts.filter(function (boxartFeature) {
               return boxartFeature.width === 150 && boxartFeature.height === 200;
           })
               .map(function (boxartProp) {
               return boxartProp.url;
           })
       };
   });
 }).concatAll(); //Flattens nested array by 1 dimension (please see demo)
```

I know I need to apply the `.concatAll()` function to remove the nested boxart array, but I can't seem to find the place where.

Please click [here for demo](https://jsbin.com/tirapi/edit?js,console)

Comment: "I have this JSON data" — That's JavaScript, not JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close. I recognize this as an exercise for Observables. Because you are looking into RxJS, it is important that you do **NOT** use indexing --> [0]. There is no concept of an index when dealing with Observables.

The trick to understanding this problem is to look closer at what `concatAll()` is doing. It takes a two-dimensional array and returns a flattened array.

`[[1,2],[3,4]] --> [1,2,3,4]`

With your current code, you are mapping the `boxartProp.url` to a nested array but the rest of your properties are not. What you more or less have right now is: `[1,2,3,[4]]`. What you want to have is an evenly nested array: `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`. The reason that is important is because `concatAll()` expects each member to be a subarray. If you haven't already seen it, I recommend watching [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-create-an-array-concatall-method) by Jafar Husain. He is amazing and implements `concatAll` from scratch in the video.

Your objective can be accomplished with just a few minor tweaks.

```
return movieLists.map(function(category) {
    return category.videos.map(function(video) {
        return video.boxarts.filter(function(boxart) {
            return boxart.width === 150;
        }).map(function(boxart) {
            return {id: video.id, title: video.title, boxart: boxart.url};
        });
    }).concatAll();
}).concatAll();
```

Notice how in the last map instead of just mapping the boxart url, we pass the video data in as well. This gives us the evenly-nested array that we need to run `concatAll()`.

The reason we have to call `concatAll()` twice is that your videos are nested within categories in your demo. The first call flattens the films and the second call flattens the categories.

[Here is the modified jsbin for your review](https://jsbin.com/hadunugoci/1/edit?js,console).

These are some great exercises to be working on. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns an array. You are storing the result of `map` in the `boxart` property.

If you don't want to store an array in `boxart`, simply store the first member (index `0`) of the array instead:

```
//...
.map(function (boxartProp) {
     return boxartProp.url;
})[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use forEach() instead of map() and store the "correct" boxart in a local variable. Remember that map() returns an array. By using forEach instead, we can check each boxart and select the correct one. I like this solution because it's easier for someone else reading your code to understand what's happening. This also allows us to just use concatAll() neatly at the end of our chain.

```
return movieLists.map(function(category){                      

return  category.videos.map(function(vids){
    var correctBoxSize = "No Proper Box Size Found"; 

    vids.boxarts.forEach(function(boxes){
        if (boxes.width === 150 && boxes.height === 200)
            {correctBoxSize = boxes.url}
        });

    return {
            "id": vids.id,
            "title": vids.title,
            "boxart": correctBoxSize
           };
})
}).concatAll()
```